# Touchpad on MacBook is shiny?

Tags: macbook, touchpad, cleaning, maintenance

I noticed that the touchpad was getting a little shiny on the middle-most part. I just want to know if there's a way to clean this and restore the laptop to its previous texture? If there's no way to restore it back, how can I protect it so that it no longer further shines?

If I got it right, this event, if goes to worse, would make the touchpad less responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens with all laptop touchpad in the market. The reason is when you use it, the friction between your fingers and the touchpad caused it to smooth out/lose original texture. And there is no way to prevent this unless you use a mouse. Also the shininess wont effect functionality of your touchpad so don't worry too much

Comment: I've read on forums that 9t will be hard to move the cursor if the touchpad is shiny because it will have a hard time detecting my finger or something? If I'm not mistaken, mice (or mouses) have a hard time navigating the cursor on a shiny surface...

Comment: With mordern mouse, it works using optical or laser that tracks the roughness of surface it is on, so you might hear the term like 400dpi, 800dpi (dots per inch). So yes, with mouse, it has hard time navigating very smooth or very uneven surfaces.

Comment: But with touchpad on laptop, it uses capactive layer. Your bare finger(s) emits negative electrons which picked up by capactive touchpad. How much the electron moves then translate to the x axis, y axis. The top layer of touchpad is a plastic protects the capacitive layer. So the smoothness/shininess of plastic layer won't effect the functionality

Comment: It could be harder for your fingers to slide on the glossy surface if they are not completely dry.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a screen protector on it. It sounds stupid, but think about it; an iPhone is just a touchpad, with a screen behind it. When you put a screen protector on it, it ought to be nice and smooth (or at least as smooth as the material can get).